# How it works Aggregate using FUN=diff

Tags: r

I have the following data frame called 'tbl'

```
a  04/01/2016 9
b  04/01/2016 14
a  04/04/2016 11
b  04/04/2016 15
a  04/05/2016 14
b  04/05/2016 20
```

where the columns are called `Asset_Type`, `Date`, and `Cumulative_P&L` respectively.

I need the output with the daily_P&L not the cumulative, i.e

```
<code>
a  04/01/2016 0
b  04/01/2016 0
a  04/04/2016 2
b  04/04/2016 1
a  04/05/2016 3
b  04/05/2016 5
```

I´m trying this kind of code but it doesn´t work

```
tbl2 <- aggregate(Cumulative_P&L~Asset_Type+Date,tbl,FUN=function(x) diff(x,1)) 
tbl2 <- with(tbl,aggregate(Cumulative_P&L~Asset_Type+Date,FUN=function(x) diff(x,1))) </code>
```

How can i use `diff` inside `aggregate` to solve it or is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

A dplyr solution using `lag` and `abs` rather than `diff`, though you get NA values rather than 0.

```
Asset_Type <- rep(c("a", "b"), 3)
Date <- rep("4/01/2016", "4/04/2016", "4/05/2016", each = 2)
Cumulative_PL <- c(9, 14, 11, 15, 14, 20)
table <- data.frame(Asset_Type,
                    Date,
                    Cumulative_PL)


table %>%
    group_by(Asset_Type) %>%
    mutate(Daily_PL = abs(Cumulative_PL - lag(Cumulative_PL)))
```

Result:

```
      Asset_Type  Date     Cumulative_PL    Daily_diff
       (fctr)    (fctr)             (dbl)        (dbl)
1          a     4/01/2016             9           NA
2          b     4/01/2016            14           NA
3          a     4/04/2016            11            2
4          b     4/04/2016            15            1
5          a     4/05/2016            14            3
6          b     4/05/2016            20            5
```

To convert the NA values into 0's:

```
table_df <- as.data.frame(table)
table_df[is.na(table_df)] <- 0
```